# highlight active menuItem in the sidebar of shinydashboard

Tags: shiny, shinydashboard, shinyjs

My question is exactly the same as what Maxime asked in [r studio community](https://community.rstudio.com/t/highlight-active-menuitem-in-the-sidebar-of-shinydashboard/36379). 
 I have run into a similar issue with my work. 
 
Since there was no response in that community, I'll repost Maxime's question here.

> Hello R users,
>
> I have a lot of hidden menuItems when I launch my shiny App. Some of
>   them are going to be shown when some buttons are clicked and some
>   other conditions met.
>
> Everything ran as expected but I would like that the active menuItem
>   is highlighted on the sidebar. This is the case with the home page
>   that is never hidden but with all the hidden (from shinyjs package)
>   menuItems, once I show them, the menuItem is not highlighted when it
>   is active.
>
> Anyone has a relatively easy solution for that?
>
> Example of what the sidebar codes can look like:
>
> in the UI for the sidebar:

```
sidebarMenu(id = "tabs",
shinyjs::useShinyjs(), 
menuItem("Product Selection", tabName = "product_selection", icon = icon("dashboard")),
shinyjs::hidden(
        div(id="Test", 
            menuItem("Test", tabName = "Test", icon = icon("chart-line")))) 
)
```

> in the server for the sidebar action:

```
observeEvent(input$look, {ID = someID shinyjs::show(id= ID,anim = TRUE) 
updateTabItems(session, "tabs", ID) })
```

> Have a nice day,
>
> Maxime

Comment: have you tried a css solution listed in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21233394/how-change-text-color-of-tab-selected-by-css) SO post?